# Angular: routing multiple id's (parent and child)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an issue in Angular with getting the id of an object (an ingredient) within another object (a dish). I want to be able to update the ingredient, for example it's name, via the update module (see below), but I am not able to get the ingredient. When I select one dish, I am for example in http://localhost:4200/dishes/3 . Here a list of ingredients is displayed, with an edit and delete button. I want to be able to click the edit button and arrive at an edit page for that specific ingredient. So for example, I should arrive at http://localhost:4200/dishes/3/ingredients/7.

However, the browserconsole gives the following error, where undefined should be the id of the dish (dishId):

```
GET http://localhost:51115/api/dishes/undefined/ingredients/20 404 (Not Found)
```

I think I need to pass the **dishId** in the params of the this.route.params.subscribe function which you can find below in the update module code example, but I have no idea how.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Update module:

```
export class IngredientUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  public ingredientForm: FormGroup;
  private dishId: number;
  private ingredient: Ingredient;
  private ingredientId: number;
  private sub: Subscription;
  private originalIngredientForUpdate: IngredientForUpdate;

  constructor(private ingredientService: IngredientService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.ingredientForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [''],
    pricePerUnit: ['']
  });

  // get route data (ingredientId)
  // here I think I need to add the dishId in some way the the params?
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
    params => {
        this.ingredientId = params['ingredientId'];

      // load ingredient
      this.ingredientService.getIngredientForDish(this.dishId, this.ingredientId)
        .subscribe(ingredient => {
          this.ingredient = ingredient;
          this.updateIngredientForm();
          this.originalIngredientForUpdate = this.ingredientForm.value;
        })
    }
  );
}
```

Get method in service:

```
getIngredientForDish(dishId: number, ingredientId: number): Observable<Ingredient> {
    return this.http.get<Ingredient>(`${this.apiUrl}/dishes/${dishId}/ingredients/${ingredientId}`)
}
```

Routing module:

```
const routes: Routes = [

  // redirect root to the dasbhoard route
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dishes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'dishes', component: DishesComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'dish-add', component: DishAddComponent },
  { path: 'dishes/:dishId', component: DishDetailComponent },
  { path: 'dish-update/:dishId', component: DishUpdateComponent },
  { path: 'dishes/:dishId/ingredient-add', component: IngredientAddComponent },
  { path: 'ingredient-update/:ingredientId', component: IngredientUpdateComponent }

// define a module
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }


  //  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dishes' },
];
```

html module contains:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/ingredient-update', ingredient.ingredientId]">
```

I've also tried modifying the routing and html module as follows, with no succes:

```
{ path: 'dishes/:dishId/ingredient-update/:ingredientId' }
[routerLink]="['/dishes', dishes.dishId, '/ingredient-update', ingredient.ingredientId]">
```

AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DishesComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    IngredientsComponent,
    IngredientAddComponent,
    IngredientSingleComponent,
    DishAddComponent,
    DishDetailComponent,
    DishUpdateComponent,
    DishDeleteComponent,
    IngredientUpdateComponent,
    IngredientDeleteComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [DishService, IngredientService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please Edit your question is your problem is not clear. What you want to achieve. Do you want to navigate to a component and pass param to it? Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Show us your routes definition.

Comment: I've updated the question, is this clear or do you need more information? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your route defines a single param: ingredientId. So you can't possibly get the dishId from the params. Change your route definition so that it contains the two params that the component needs: the dishId, and the ingredientId. Then change the link to that route of course, to pass the dishId as parameter, and then get the dishId from the params of the activated route.

Comment: Can you maybe give an example in code of how I could do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After trial and error I am glad that I found the solution:

As I already mentioned in my question, the dishId needed to be added to the params. Using two id's works as follows:

```
// get route data (dishId and ingredientId)
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(
   params => {
      this.dishId = params['dishId'];
      this.ingredientId = params['ingredientId'];
```

I use ASP.NET Core and EF Core for my backend. The Ingredient Entitity did already have a DishId, but I forgot to add the DishId to the ingredient dto, so it was never passed back.

Next to this, I needed to add dishId to my ingredient model in Angular as well.

Then I changed the routing to:

```
{ path: 'dishes/:dishId/ingredients/:ingredientId', component: IngredientUpdateComponent }
```

And the html link to:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['/dishes', ingredient.dishId, 'ingredients', ingredient.ingredientId]">
            Edit
          </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error which has the same scenario. In my case the parent id in the route was different from the one defined in the component. Resolving that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

your route:
`foo/bar/1/2/3`

your route dec-tion:
`path: 'foo/bar/:firstId/:secondId/:thirdId'`

In your component:

```
  const firstId = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('firstId')
  const secondId = this.activeRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('secondId')
```

Next you know.